# Best way to troubleshoot a GPO that is being applied but not working?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, group-policy

We are using GPO to push out proxy settings and it is applying and working for most users. There is a small group of users, admittedly in a separate OU, that it's just not working for. I can do a gpresult /R and see that the GPO is being applied. However, when I check the proxy settings it's not using the correct proxy.

This GPO is at the root of the domain. How can I further test this?

Comment: Did you gpupdate?

Comment: Yes. This GPO has been out for months but the users are just not complaining. Their work flow keeps them off the terminal servers 95% of the time.

Comment: Just to clarify, you ran gpupdate on the individual workstations? (I don't think my question was clear)

Comment: No, the machines they are using are not part of the domain. They are logging into terminal servers and that is where the gpupdate was ran. The GPO is applied to the user, not their local machines.

Comment: Misunderstood the question, my apologies.

Comment: Do you have multiple policies that set proxy settings? What happens if you put those computers in a different OU? Also, try gpresult /h - it shows some more details regarding what has been applied (or not) and why.

Answer (score 0):

Built-in GPO for proxy settings is messed up. Not only you need to set up settings for each version of IE (and download admx files for ie11), they are really sometimes just dont work.

Therefore I suggest modifying registry instead. In

```
User Configuration > Preferences > Registry
```

you can specify any custom registry values you want.
In particular, you can modify proxy settings here:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\InternetSettings
```

Pros of this aproach is that they are version-independent, i.e. they will apply to any version of IE

Comment: Cons are that this method would require you to deal with some hex key that contains all settings (because that's the only way AFAIK). Also, this is probably not a supported method.

Comment: no, theres a separate key for each setting. ProxyEnable (dword), ProxyServer (reg_sz) etc

Comment: We went down that road in my organization, and those keys were either unreliable or not version-independent (can't remember, was long time ago). The only registry-option that worked was this hex key, that contains all settings. I hope Stratag3m will try your keys, and report back...